# Why does this C++ template produce an error asking for the missing semicolon?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm just typing in some code explaining how binders work, from "Beyond the Standard Library" by Bjorn Karlsson. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express, and am getting a missing semi colon error.

This bit seems fine:

```
// template for a simple function object
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<typename R, typename T, typename Arg>
  class simple_bind_t {
    typedef R (T::*fn) (Arg);  // fn defines a type - a ptr to member fn
                               // of object T, returning an R, and taking Arg

    fn _fn;                    // the function object owns a pointer to function.
    T  _t;                     // it also owns an object of type T.

  public:

    simple_bind_t(fn f, const T& t):
             _fn(fn), _t(t) {} // instantiate mber variables

    R operator()(Arg& a) 
    { 
      return (_t->_fn)(a);    // invoke the member function on t, pass a as an arg.
    }

  };
```

So that bit is all fine. But then when I go to define the actual function that creates a function object, (see code snippet below), I get a little red line underneath the `R` of the line `R (T::*fn)(Arg),`. When I roll my mouse over it says - `Error: expected a ';'`).

```
template <class R, class T, class Arg> 
   simple_bind_t<R,T,Arg> simple_bind (
     R (T::*fn)(Arg),                     
     const T& t,
     const placeholder&)
   { return simple_bind_t<R,T,Arg>(fn,t); } // construct an object of simple_bind_t<R,T,Arg>
                                        // pass it pointer to the member function, fn
                                        // and the object of type T to bind to, t
```

Can anyone spot where the syntax error is?

Comment: Did you try with GCC 4.8 or CLANG 3.3 ?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 express. No I didn't try gcc 4.8 or clang 3.3. Do you recommend trying that?

Comment: Please post a minimal complete code. At the moment it’s impossible to reproduce (and thus diagnose) the problem.

Comment: This actually is the complete code. I don't know what more I can post.  This is not a compiler error, but a syntax error picked up by Visual Studio 2010 express - prior to compiling. Sorry perhaps I was not clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ve made a typo here:

```
simple_bind_t(fn f, const T& t):
         _fn(fn), _t(t) {} // instantiate mber variables
// ----------^^
```

`fn` names a *type*, you meant to use the argument, `f`. There may be other errors but since you didn’t post a complete enough code (for instance, the definition of `placeholder` is missing), it’s impossible to find them.

Comment: Actually it was the fact that definition of `placeholder` was missing that was causing Visual Studio to give me that red line.